# How to add dynamic multiples markers on flutter google map?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, location

I'm browsing for it from yesterday and couldn't get any satisfying solution.

I used [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin for the get current user location and defined it from initState() method.

I set static markers on the map but want to get dynamic markers on the map.

My Code:

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
 Position position;
 Set<Marker> markers = Set();
List<Marker> addMarkers = [
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("Quark city Id"),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: "Quark city",
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      position:  LatLng(30.706129, 76.692422)
    ),
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("Godrej Company Id"),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: "Godrej Company",
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
      position:  LatLng(30.701916, 76.695063)
    ),
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("Radha Swami Chouwk Id"),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: "Radha Swami Chouwk",
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
      position:  LatLng(30.703092, 76.701069)
    ),
  ];




@override
  void initState() {
    markers.addAll(addMarkers); // add markers to the list
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();

  }
//Current user's marker:
 void getCurrentLocation()async{
    Position pos= await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      position = pos;

      // added markers on user current location
      markers.add(Marker( 
        markerId: MarkerId("current Id"),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: "Current",
        ),
        position: LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
     ));
    });
  }
```

build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Google Map"), centerTitle: true,),
      body:position == null
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
      :GoogleMap(
        ......
        ......
        markers: markers
       )
    );
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean dynamic ?

Comment: I mean, not  use static latlng , see i used static latlng.

Comment: So, you want to retrieve latlong by city name ?

Comment: yes , nearby my location.

Comment: you can call using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&key=API_KEY` this url

Comment: Sir, would you please implement it into the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203744/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-shruti-ramnandan-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) - Flutter's official Google Maps plugin. You can use GoogleMap's [markers](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/markers.html) property to create multiple map markers.

Create a marker by generating a Marker object.

```dart
final Marker marker = Marker(
  markerId: markerId,
  position: LatLng(
    center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
    center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
  ),
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: markerIdVal, snippet: '*'),
  onTap: () => _onMarkerTapped(markerId),
  onDragEnd: (LatLng position) => _onMarkerDragEnd(markerId, position),
  onDrag: (LatLng position) => _onMarkerDrag(markerId, position),
);
```

Then set the marker on the GoogleMap widget.

```dart
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
    zoom: 11.0,
  ),
  markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
),
```

You can check out the [plugin's demo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart) for the complete sample.